Typescript for LWC Developer Preview - what are the implications?
Salesforce have released Typescript for LWCs as a developer preview in Winter '25.
Being a developer preview, my understanding is it's not guaranteed to go GA at all, let alone any breaking changes they might make.
I feel like this developer preview is a bit different to others, because this is all about supporting typescript within your coding environment, not on the Salesforce server itself.
I'd like to make this part of our development process, but I'm trying to get my head around the implications if Salesforce either discontinue or significantly change the implementation.
From my understanding, it won't have any affect on the LWCs in your org, because it's only javascript that's deployed to the org.
I guess the real question is, what happens if Salesforce stop supporting this?
Will our VS Code projects break, or will there be significant re-factoring?
Or is it more likely we'll just need to remove the relevant Typescript stuff from our projects and revert to Javascript?
A sub question is, what does setting "salesforcedx-vscode-lwc.preview.typeScriptSupport": true in the settings.json file actually do?  And how does it relate to the Salesforce CLI?

I think you correct to be cautios since it's a dev preview and you can't guarantie how long would it take to move it to Beta or GA. And we know that some dev features can take a long time to move from DevPreview.
From what I know Salesforce was using TS for quite some time behind the scenes, because you can see interface files being generated for Apex methods and LWC modules.

Considering the risks if Salesforce stops supporting it. I do think that it won't be high effort to move back. TS generates JS files behind the scenes so you'll be able to add them back. You can also retrieve JS files from the org.
So in total I think it's medium risk, so it should be ok to experiment with it new or smaller size project, but I wouldn't recommend migrating existing big projects due to potential issues or limitations in support that can arise.
